# Category wont show in url permalink WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get category in my page url in WordPress, but I cannot get it to work correctly. I've tried to go to settings > permalinks and chose the custom structure and added these parameters: /%category%/%postname%/, but the site url does not update. After adding the parameters and refreshing the page normally aswell as with a cache flush a page with a category assigned to it does not have the site url updated, the postname seems to function correctly though.

Currently there is only one plugin running on the website, Events Manager, other then that I'm running the latest WordPress version.

I added the category functionality in my functions.php file with the following code.

```
   function myplugin_settings() {  
    // Add tag metabox to page
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page'); 
    // Add category metabox to page
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}

add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_settings' );
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add an action to your functions.php file to do this. Remove that code and go to Admin->Settings-Permalinks and add "/%category%/%postname%/" to the "Custom Structure" and save

Comment: Like i said i did use the custom structure in Admin > settings > permalinks. Now that i deleted the action in functions.php the category's are not showing in the backend anymore. I clicked on a page again and resaved it. Still the url doesnt show the category in the url.

Comment: Possibly related :
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786110/permalink-not-working-on-custom-post-and-category

Comment: I'm trying to get category's on pages not posts. I dont have enough expierence to write code though.

Comment: You can try a plugin:
[link]https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/